# RewriteEngine is not allowed with dynamic <Directory>

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

I currently have a variable host setup using dnsmasq on OS X 10.14.  My base folder is `~/Sites`.  I can have a folder `~/Sites/{whatever}` which I can load via `http://{whatever}.test/`.  I am trying to use mod_rewrite for one of my projects, but RewriteEngine is not allowed for some reason.

I have my httpd-vhosts.conf file setup like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/{Username}/Sites/%1"
    ServerName sites.test
    ServerAlias *.test
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    <Directory "/Users/{Username}/Sites/%1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my .htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^read$ read.php
RewriteRule ^read/$ read.php
RewriteRule ^read/([\w\s]+)$ read.php?s=$1
RewriteRule ^read/([\w\s]+)/$ read.php?s=$1
RewriteRule ^read/([\w\s]+)/(\d+) read.php?s=$1&p=$2
```

It doesn't matter what I have in my .htaccess file, as long as `RewriteEngine On` is there it errors out.
While using %1 in my Directory tag I get the following error:

```
/Users/{Username}/Sites/reader/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here
```

I can't seem to find a way around this without hard coding the directory, but that defeats the purpose of the variable host setup.

If I do hard code the directory the site works just like it should - so everything else is working.

---

## Solved

I managed to figure it out.

In my httpd.conf I had this:

```
#<Directory />
#    AllowOverride none
#    Require all denied
#</Directory>
```

Notice the commenting out.

I changed it to this:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Directory "/Users/{Username}/Sites/%1">
> ```

`%1` is not valid syntax here. I don't think you necessarily need to be specific, as the directory being accessed is already controlled by the (virtual) document root. So, you could, in theory use the `<DirectoryMatch>` directive instead and providing it matches the appropriate directory *pattern* it would be sufficient.

HOWEVER, the `AllowOverride` directive is not permitted in `<DirectoryMatch>` containers, only in non-regex `<Directory>` containers, so this would restrict you to do something like the following as a workaround:

```
<Directory "/Users/{Username}/Sites">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/Users/{Username}/Sites/[a-z]+">
    Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
```

`[a-z]+` will match "reader".

**UPDATE:**

> I changed it to this:
>
> ```
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> and it now works.

This enables access to the *entire server* - which is undesirable (and the Apache docs specifically warn against doing this for security *and* performance reasons.)

You should be as restrictive as possible - as above (which is the idea behind using the restrictive `<Directory>` container inside the vHost in the first place).

Comment: Thank you.  The only reason I'm comfortable allowing access to the entire server is due to it being solely on my personal Macbook which nobody will have remote access to.  I don't feel comfortable allowing dynamic vhosts on my public server and I also don't feel like I would have the need for them either.  I have updated to what you've suggested (with minor changes to the regex) and it seems to be working fine.